# Is there a pseudocontractive mapping that is not strictly pseudocontractive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $H$, a mapping $T:H\rightarrow H$ is said to be pseudocontractive if $$\|Tx-Ty\|^2\leq \|x-y\|^2+\|(x-Tx)-(y-Ty)\|^2\,\,\, \forall x,y\in H,$$
and it is strictly pseudocontractive if for some $k\in (0,1)$, we have 
$$\|Tx-Ty\|^2\leq \|x-y\|^2+k\|(x-Tx)-(y-Ty)\|^2\,\,\, \forall x,y\in H.$$

Example: $Tx=-2x$ is strictly pseudocontractive. Every strictly pseudocontractive mapping is pseudocontractive and it is generally known that nonexpansive mappings are pseudocontractive.

Question: Can someone give me an example (if it exists) of a pseudocontractive mapping that is not strictly pseudocontractive?

Comment: I've noticed that you've tagged a handful of your own questions with the (multisets) tag, none of which actually involves [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). The same with differential/algebraic topology/geometry. Please read the tag descriptions and try to be more discerning in the future.

Comment: @epimorphic, there is actually a multivalued version of it. And I truely hope that anyone that has knowledge of multisets can effectively contribute. Thanks

Comment: I apologize if that's the case. If you could edit the question to state how multisets are involved, that would be great, and feel free to add the tag back in when you do.